# glsl parser using pyparsing giving AttributeErrors

Tags: python, python-3.x, glsl, pyparsing

I'm trying to update this [glsl-parser](https://github.com/rougier/glsl-parser) which uses an old pyparsing version and python2.x to python3.x & the newest pyparsing version (2.1.9 atm).

I don't know which pyparsing version was using the original source code but it must be quite old because is still using `keepOriginalText` helper method, after reading pyparsing [news](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/News) I've seen this comment `Removed keepOriginalText helper method, which was deprecated ages ago. Superceded by originalTextFor.`

Anyway, here's the first attempt of the port using python3.5.1 & pyparsing==2.1.9:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2014, Nicolas P. Rougier
# Distributed under the (new) BSD License. See LICENSE.txt for more info.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
import pyparsing

keywords = ("attribute const uniform varying break continue do for while"
            "if else"
            "in out inout"
            "float int void bool true false"
            "lowp mediump highp precision invariant"
            "discard return"
            "mat2 mat3 mat4"
            "vec2 vec3 vec4 ivec2 ivec3 ivec4 bvec2 bvec3 bvec4 sampler2D samplerCube"
            "struct")
reserved = ("asm"
            "class union enum typedef template this packed"
            "goto switch default"
            "inline noinline volatile public static extern external"
            "interface flat long short double half fixed unsigned superp"
            "input output"
            "hvec2 hvec3 hvec4 dvec2 dvec3 dvec4 fvec2 fvec3 fvec4 sampler1D sampler3D"
            "sampler1DShadow sampler2DShadow"
            "sampler2DRect sampler3DRect sampler2DRectShadow"
            "sizeof cast"
            "namespace using")
precision = "lowp mediump high"
storage = "const uniform attribute varying"


# Tokens
# ----------------------------------
LPAREN = pyparsing.Literal("(").suppress()
RPAREN = pyparsing.Literal(")").suppress()
LBRACK = pyparsing.Literal("[").suppress()
RBRACK = pyparsing.Literal("]").suppress()
LBRACE = pyparsing.Literal("{").suppress()
RBRACE = pyparsing.Literal("}").suppress()
IDENTIFIER = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas + '_', pyparsing.alphanums + '_')
TYPE = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas + '_', pyparsing.alphanums + "_")
END = pyparsing.Literal(";").suppress()
INT = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums)
FLOAT = pyparsing.Regex(
    '[+-]?(((\d+\.\d*)|(\d*\.\d+))([eE][-+]?\d+)?)|(\d*[eE][+-]?\d+)')
STORAGE = pyparsing.Regex('|'.join(storage.split(' ')))
PRECISION = pyparsing.Regex('|'.join(precision.split(' ')))
STRUCT = pyparsing.Literal("struct").suppress()


# ------------------------
def get_prototypes(code):
    """
    Get all function declarations

    Code example
    ------------

    mediump vec3 function_1(vec4);
    vec3 function_2(float a, float b);
    """

    PARAMETER = pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION).setResultsName("precision") +
                                TYPE.setResultsName("type") +
                                pyparsing.Optional(IDENTIFIER).setResultsName("name"))
    PARAMETERS = pyparsing.delimitedList(PARAMETER).setResultsName(
        "arg", listAllMatches=True)
    PROTOTYPE = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION).setResultsName("precision") +
                 TYPE.setResultsName("type") +
                 IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
                 LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(PARAMETERS).setResultsName("args") + RPAREN +
                 END)
    PROTOTYPE.ignore(pyparsing.cStyleComment)

    for (token, start, end) in PROTOTYPE.scanString(code):
        print(token.precision, token.type, token.name, '(',)
        for arg in token.args:
            print(arg.precision, arg.type, arg.name, ',',)
        print(')')


# ------------------------
def get_functions(code):
    """
    Get all function definitions

    Code example
    ------------

    mediump vec3 compute_normal(vec4);
    """

    PARAMETER = pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION).setResultsName("precision") +
                                TYPE.setResultsName("type") +
                                pyparsing.Optional(IDENTIFIER).setResultsName("name"))
    PARAMETERS = pyparsing.delimitedList(PARAMETER).setResultsName(
        "arg", listAllMatches=True)
    FUNCTION = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION).setResultsName("precision") +
                TYPE.setResultsName("type") +
                IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
                LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(PARAMETERS).setResultsName("args") + RPAREN +
                pyparsing.nestedExpr("{", "}").setParseAction(pyparsing.originalTextFor).setResultsName("code"))
    FUNCTION.ignore(pyparsing.cStyleComment)

    for (token, start, end) in FUNCTION.scanString(code):
        print(token.precision, token.type, token.name, '(',)
        for arg in token.args:
            print(arg.precision, arg.type, arg.name, ',',)
        print(') { ... }')

        # print token.code
        # print code[start:end]


# ------------------------
def get_version(code):
    """
    Get shader version (if specified)

    Code example
    ------------

    #version 120
    """

    VERSION = (
        pyparsing.Literal("#") + pyparsing.Keyword("version")).suppress() + INT
    for (token, start, end) in VERSION.scanString(code):
        version = token[0]
        # print code[start:end]
    return version

# ------------------------


def get_declarations(code):
    """
    Get all declarations prefixed with a storage qualifier.

    Code example
    ------------

    uniform lowp vec4 fg_color = vec4(1),
                      bg_color = vec4(vec3(0),1);
    """

    # Callable expression
    EXPRESSION = pyparsing.Forward()
    ARG = pyparsing.Group(EXPRESSION) | IDENTIFIER | FLOAT | INT
    ARGS = pyparsing.delimitedList(ARG)
    EXPRESSION << IDENTIFIER + \
        pyparsing.Group(LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(ARGS) + RPAREN)

    # Value
    VALUE = (EXPRESSION | pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + "_()+-/*")
             ).setParseAction(pyparsing.originalTextFor)

    # Single declaration
    VARIABLE = (IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
                pyparsing.Optional(LBRACK +
                                   (INT | IDENTIFIER).setResultsName("size")
                                   + RBRACK) +
                pyparsing.Optional(pyparsing.Literal("=").suppress() + VALUE.setResultsName("value")))

    # Several declarations at once
    DECLARATION = (STORAGE.setResultsName("storage") +
                   pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION).setResultsName("precision") +
                   TYPE.setResultsName("type") +
                   pyparsing.delimitedList(VARIABLE.setResultsName("variable", listAllMatches=True)) +
                   END)
    DECLARATION.ignore(pyparsing.cStyleComment)

    for (tokens, start, end) in DECLARATION.scanString(code):
        for token in tokens.variable:
            print(tokens.storage, tokens.precision, tokens.type,)
            print(token.name, token.size)


# ------------------------
def get_definitions(code):
    """
    Get all structure definitions and associated declarations.

    Code example
    ------------

    uniform struct Light {
        vec4 position;
        vec3 color;
    } light0, light1;
    """

    # Single declaration
    DECLARATION = pyparsing.Group(IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
                                  pyparsing.Optional(LBRACK +
                                                     (INT | IDENTIFIER).setResultsName("size") +
                                                     RBRACK))
    # Several declarations at once
    DECLARATIONS = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION) +
                    TYPE +
                    pyparsing.delimitedList(DECLARATION) +
                    END)

    # Definition + declarations
    DEFINITION = (STRUCT +
                  IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
                  LBRACE + pyparsing.OneOrMore(DECLARATIONS).setResultsName('content') + RBRACE +
                  pyparsing.Optional(pyparsing.delimitedList(DECLARATION.setResultsName("declarations", listAllMatches=True))) +
                  END)
    DEFINITION.ignore(pyparsing.cStyleComment)

    for (tokens, start, end) in DEFINITION.scanString(code):
        for token in tokens.declarations:
            print(tokens.name, token.name)
            # print tokens.content


# ----------------
def resolve(code):
    """
    Expand const and preprocessor definitions in order to get constant values.

    Return the transformed code
    """

    constants = {}

    DEFINITION = (pyparsing.Literal("#") + pyparsing.Literal("define") +
                  IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
                  pyparsing.restOfLine.setResultsName("value"))

    VALUE = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + "_()+-/*")
    DECLARATION = (pyparsing.Literal("const") +
                   TYPE.setResultsName("type") +
                   IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
                   pyparsing.Literal("=") +
                   VALUE.setResultsName("value") +
                   pyparsing.Literal(";"))
    REFERENCE = pyparsing.Forward()

    def process_definition(s, l, t):
        value = REFERENCE.transformString(t.value)
        constants[t.name] = value
        REFERENCE << pyparsing.MatchFirst(
            map(pyparsing.Keyword, constants.keys()))
        return "#define " + t.name + " " + value

    def process_declaration(s, l, t):
        value = REFERENCE.transformString(t.value)
        constants[t.name] = value
        REFERENCE << pyparsing.MatchFirst(
            map(pyparsing.Keyword, constants.keys()))
        return "const " + t.type + " " + t.name + "=" + value + ";"

    def process_reference(s, l, t):
        return constants[t[0]]

    REFERENCE.setParseAction(process_reference)
    DEFINITION.setParseAction(process_definition)
    DECLARATION.setParseAction(process_declaration)
    EXPANDER = REFERENCE | DEFINITION | DECLARATION

    code = EXPANDER.transformString(code)
    for key, val in constants.items():
        constants[key] = eval(val)

    return code, constants


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':

    code = """
#version 120

#define A (1)
const int B=(A+2);
#define C (B+3)
const int D=C+4;

uniform float array[D];

struct Point {
    vec4 position;
    float size;
};

uniform struct Light {
    vec4 position;
    vec3 color;
} light0, light1;

const float PI = 3.14159265358979323846264;
const float SQRT_2 = 1.4142135623730951;

uniform vec4 fg_color = vec4(1),
             bg_color = vec4(vec3(0),1);

mediump vec3 compute_normal(vec4 position, vec3 orientation);
vec3 /* */ compute_light(vec4, vec3, float intensity)
{
   vec3 hello;
   vec3 hello;
}

"""
code, _ = resolve(code)
print("GLSL version: %s\n" % get_version(code))

get_definitions(code)
get_declarations(code)
get_prototypes(code)
get_functions(code)

# code = """
# #if A
# #if B
# #if C
# #endif
# #endif
# #endif
# """

# IF = (pyparsing.Literal('#') + (pyparsing.Keyword('if') | pyparsing.Keyword('ifdef') | pyparsing.Keyword('ifndef')))
# ENDIF = (pyparsing.Literal('#') + pyparsing.Keyword('endif'))
# MACRO = (IF + pyparsing.restOfLine() +
#          SkipTo(ENDIF, include=True)).setParseAction(pyparsing.originalTextFor)
# for (tokens, start, end) in MACRO.scanString(code):
#     print tokens
```

When you try running the above mcve code you'll get:

```
GLSL version: 120

('Light', 'light0')
('Light', 'light1')
d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py:3536: SyntaxWarning: Cannot combine element of type <type 'int'> with ParserElement
  matchExpr = locMarker("_original_start") + expr + endlocMarker("_original_end")
d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py:3536: SyntaxWarning: Cannot combine element of type <type 'NoneType'> with ParserElement
  matchExpr = locMarker("_original_start") + expr + endlocMarker("_original_end")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\sources\personal\python\pyqt\pyshaders\gui\glsl-parser.py", line 311, in <module>
    get_declarations(code)
  File "D:\sources\personal\python\pyqt\pyshaders\gui\glsl-parser.py", line 173, in get_declarations
    for (tokens, start, end) in DECLARATION.scanString(code):
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1258, in scanString
    nextLoc,tokens = parseFn( instring, preloc, callPreParse=False )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1084, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 2576, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1084, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 2576, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1084, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 3038, in parseImpl
    loc, tokens = self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1084, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 2576, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1110, in _parseNoCache
    tokens = fn( instring, tokensStart, retTokens )
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 831, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 3542, in originalTextFor
    matchExpr.setParseAction(extractText)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setParseAction'
```

I'm still in the process of learning pyparsing, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`originalTextFor` is not a parse action, but a helper method that attaches a parse action to a defined expression. In your example it is used in two places:

```
# Value
VALUE = (EXPRESSION | pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + "_()+-/*")
         ).setParseAction(pyparsing.originalTextFor)

FUNCTION = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION).setResultsName("precision") +
            TYPE.setResultsName("type") +
            IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
            LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(PARAMETERS).setResultsName("args") + RPAREN +
            pyparsing.nestedExpr("{", "}").setParseAction(pyparsing.originalTextFor).setResultsName("code"))
```

change these to:

```
# Value
VALUE = pyparsing.originalTextFor(EXPRESSION |
                                  pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + "_()+-/*"))

FUNCTION = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION).setResultsName("precision") +
            TYPE.setResultsName("type") +
            IDENTIFIER.setResultsName("name") +
            LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(PARAMETERS).setResultsName("args") + RPAREN +
            pyparsing.originalTextFor(pyparsing.nestedExpr("{", "}")).setResultsName("code"))
```

You might find that the more recent pyparsing form of `setResultsName` to be a little cleaner-looking, but the old form still works fine:

```
FUNCTION = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION)("precision") +
            TYPE("type") +
            IDENTIFIER("name") +
            LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(PARAMETERS)("args") + RPAREN +
            pyparsing.originalTextFor(pyparsing.nestedExpr("{", "}"))("code"))
```

If you make this change, those places that use `listAllMatches` are handled by adding a '*' to the name argument:

```
pyparsing.delimitedList(VARIABLE("variable*"))
```

Comment: I can see you're the main author of pyparsing, first of all, congratulations for the good job! I must to say is a really neat module you've written there. I think using your module for the creation of a [little glsl editor widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700568/tweakable-values-on-qscintilla-widget) could be a good idea . I've wrapped out all your advices in a new answer, if you got any other good recommendations/advices about the current glsl parser, please let me know, I'm sure the current version is far away from being perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Paul McGuire advices, here's a working version which uses python3.5.1 and pyparsing 2.1.9:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2014, Nicolas P. Rougier
# Distributed under the (new) BSD License. See LICENSE.txt for more info.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
import pyparsing

keywords = ("attribute const uniform varying break continue do for while"
            "if else"
            "in out inout"
            "float int void bool true false"
            "lowp mediump highp precision invariant"
            "discard return"
            "mat2 mat3 mat4"
            "vec2 vec3 vec4 ivec2 ivec3 ivec4 bvec2 bvec3 bvec4 sampler2D samplerCube"
            "struct")
reserved = ("asm"
            "class union enum typedef template this packed"
            "goto switch default"
            "inline noinline volatile public static extern external"
            "interface flat long short double half fixed unsigned superp"
            "input output"
            "hvec2 hvec3 hvec4 dvec2 dvec3 dvec4 fvec2 fvec3 fvec4 sampler1D sampler3D"
            "sampler1DShadow sampler2DShadow"
            "sampler2DRect sampler3DRect sampler2DRectShadow"
            "sizeof cast"
            "namespace using")
precision = "lowp mediump high"
storage = "const uniform attribute varying"


# Tokens
# ----------------------------------
LPAREN = pyparsing.Literal("(").suppress()
RPAREN = pyparsing.Literal(")").suppress()
LBRACK = pyparsing.Literal("[").suppress()
RBRACK = pyparsing.Literal("]").suppress()
LBRACE = pyparsing.Literal("{").suppress()
RBRACE = pyparsing.Literal("}").suppress()
IDENTIFIER = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas + '_', pyparsing.alphanums + '_')
TYPE = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas + '_', pyparsing.alphanums + "_")
END = pyparsing.Literal(";").suppress()
INT = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums)
FLOAT = pyparsing.Regex(
    '[+-]?(((\d+\.\d*)|(\d*\.\d+))([eE][-+]?\d+)?)|(\d*[eE][+-]?\d+)')
STORAGE = pyparsing.Regex('|'.join(storage.split(' ')))
PRECISION = pyparsing.Regex('|'.join(precision.split(' ')))
STRUCT = pyparsing.Literal("struct").suppress()


# ------------------------
def get_prototypes(code):
    """
    Get all function declarations

    Code example
    ------------

    mediump vec3 function_1(vec4);
    vec3 function_2(float a, float b);
    """

    PARAMETER = pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION)("precision") +
                                TYPE("type") +
                                pyparsing.Optional(IDENTIFIER)("name"))
    PARAMETERS = pyparsing.delimitedList(PARAMETER)(
        "arg*")
    PROTOTYPE = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION)("precision") +
                 TYPE("type") +
                 IDENTIFIER("name") +
                 LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(PARAMETERS)("args") + RPAREN +
                 END)
    PROTOTYPE.ignore(pyparsing.cStyleComment)

    for (token, start, end) in PROTOTYPE.scanString(code):
        print(token.precision, token.type, token.name, '(',)
        for arg in token.args:
            print(arg.precision, arg.type, arg.name, ',',)
        print(')')


# ------------------------
def get_functions(code):
    """
    Get all function definitions

    Code example
    ------------

    mediump vec3 compute_normal(vec4);
    """

    PARAMETER = pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION)("precision") +
                                TYPE("type") +
                                pyparsing.Optional(IDENTIFIER)("name"))
    PARAMETERS = pyparsing.delimitedList(PARAMETER)(
        "arg*")
    FUNCTION = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION)("precision") +
                TYPE("type") +
                IDENTIFIER("name") +
                LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(PARAMETERS)("args") + RPAREN +
                pyparsing.originalTextFor(pyparsing.nestedExpr("{", "}"))("code"))
    FUNCTION.ignore(pyparsing.cStyleComment)

    for (token, start, end) in FUNCTION.scanString(code):
        print(token.precision, token.type, token.name, '(',)
        for arg in token.args:
            print(arg.precision, arg.type, arg.name, ',',)
        print(') { ... }')

        # print token.code
        # print code[start:end]


# ------------------------
def get_version(code):
    """
    Get shader version (if specified)

    Code example
    ------------

    #version 120
    """

    VERSION = (
        pyparsing.Literal("#") + pyparsing.Keyword("version")).suppress() + INT
    for (token, start, end) in VERSION.scanString(code):
        version = token[0]
        # print code[start:end]
    return version

# ------------------------


def get_declarations(code):
    """
    Get all declarations prefixed with a storage qualifier.

    Code example
    ------------

    uniform lowp vec4 fg_color = vec4(1),
                      bg_color = vec4(vec3(0),1);
    """

    # Callable expression
    EXPRESSION = pyparsing.Forward()
    ARG = pyparsing.Group(EXPRESSION) | IDENTIFIER | FLOAT | INT
    ARGS = pyparsing.delimitedList(ARG)
    EXPRESSION << IDENTIFIER + \
        pyparsing.Group(LPAREN + pyparsing.Optional(ARGS) + RPAREN)

    # Value
    VALUE = pyparsing.originalTextFor(EXPRESSION |
                                      pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + "_()+-/*"))

    # Single declaration
    VARIABLE = (IDENTIFIER("name") +
                pyparsing.Optional(LBRACK +
                                   (INT | IDENTIFIER)("size")
                                   + RBRACK) +
                pyparsing.Optional(pyparsing.Literal("=").suppress() + VALUE("value")))

    # Several declarations at once
    DECLARATION = (STORAGE("storage") +
                   pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION)("precision") +
                   TYPE("type") +
                   pyparsing.delimitedList(VARIABLE("variable*")) +
                   END)
    DECLARATION.ignore(pyparsing.cStyleComment)

    for (tokens, start, end) in DECLARATION.scanString(code):
        for token in tokens.variable:
            print(tokens.storage, tokens.precision, tokens.type,)
            print(token.name, token.size)


# ------------------------
def get_definitions(code):
    """
    Get all structure definitions and associated declarations.

    Code example
    ------------

    uniform struct Light {
        vec4 position;
        vec3 color;
    } light0, light1;
    """

    # Single declaration
    DECLARATION = pyparsing.Group(IDENTIFIER("name") +
                                  pyparsing.Optional(LBRACK +
                                                     (INT | IDENTIFIER)("size") +
                                                     RBRACK))
    # Several declarations at once
    DECLARATIONS = (pyparsing.Optional(PRECISION) +
                    TYPE +
                    pyparsing.delimitedList(DECLARATION) +
                    END)

    # Definition + declarations
    DEFINITION = (STRUCT +
                  IDENTIFIER("name") +
                  LBRACE + pyparsing.OneOrMore(DECLARATIONS)('content') + RBRACE +
                  pyparsing.Optional(pyparsing.delimitedList(DECLARATION("declarations*"))) +
                  END)
    DEFINITION.ignore(pyparsing.cStyleComment)

    for (tokens, start, end) in DEFINITION.scanString(code):
        for token in tokens.declarations:
            print(tokens.name, token.name)
            # print tokens.content


# ----------------
def resolve(code):
    """
    Expand const and preprocessor definitions in order to get constant values.

    Return the transformed code
    """

    constants = {}

    DEFINITION = (pyparsing.Literal("#") + pyparsing.Literal("define") +
                  IDENTIFIER("name") +
                  pyparsing.restOfLine("value"))

    VALUE = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + "_()+-/*")
    DECLARATION = (pyparsing.Literal("const") +
                   TYPE("type") +
                   IDENTIFIER("name") +
                   pyparsing.Literal("=") +
                   VALUE("value") +
                   pyparsing.Literal(";"))
    REFERENCE = pyparsing.Forward()

    def process_definition(s, l, t):
        value = REFERENCE.transformString(t.value)
        constants[t.name] = value
        REFERENCE << pyparsing.MatchFirst(
            map(pyparsing.Keyword, constants.keys()))
        return "#define " + t.name + " " + value

    def process_declaration(s, l, t):
        value = REFERENCE.transformString(t.value)
        constants[t.name] = value
        REFERENCE << pyparsing.MatchFirst(
            map(pyparsing.Keyword, constants.keys()))
        return "const " + t.type + " " + t.name + "=" + value + ";"

    def process_reference(s, l, t):
        return constants[t[0]]

    REFERENCE.setParseAction(process_reference)
    DEFINITION.setParseAction(process_definition)
    DECLARATION.setParseAction(process_declaration)
    EXPANDER = REFERENCE | DEFINITION | DECLARATION

    code = EXPANDER.transformString(code)
    for key, val in constants.items():
        constants[key] = eval(val)

    return code, constants


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':

    code = """
#version 120

#define A (1)
const int B=(A+2);
#define C (B+3)
const int D=C+4;

uniform float array[D];

struct Point {
    vec4 position;
    float size;
};

uniform struct Light {
    vec4 position;
    vec3 color;
} light0, light1;

const float PI = 3.14159265358979323846264;
const float SQRT_2 = 1.4142135623730951;

uniform vec4 fg_color = vec4(1),
             bg_color = vec4(vec3(0),1);

mediump vec3 compute_normal(vec4 position, vec3 orientation);
vec3 /* */ compute_light(vec4, vec3, float intensity)
{
   vec3 hello;
   vec3 hello;
}

"""
code, _ = resolve(code)
print("GLSL version: %s\n" % get_version(code))

get_definitions(code)
get_declarations(code)
get_prototypes(code)
get_functions(code)

# code = """
# #if A
# #if B
# #if C
# #endif
# #endif
# #endif
# """

# IF = (pyparsing.Literal('#') + (pyparsing.Keyword('if') | pyparsing.Keyword('ifdef') | pyparsing.Keyword('ifndef')))
# ENDIF = (pyparsing.Literal('#') + pyparsing.Keyword('endif'))
# MACRO = (IF + pyparsing.restOfLine() +
#          SkipTo(ENDIF, include=True)).setParseAction(pyparsing.originalTextFor)
# for (tokens, start, end) in MACRO.scanString(code):
#     print tokens
```